# How to create edge class target different vetex class in orientdb?

Tags: orientdb

[image]For example, a company has many shareholders, some are natural man, some are companies.

I need to create a edge class that target vertex type are natural man or company.

But I can only select one class in "From Vertex" dropbox

Comment: Hi, what version are you using? Could you explain better? Thx

Comment: I'm using 2.2.x

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I've undertsand correctly, please correct me if i'm wrong but, you want an edge that is able to connect a Shareholder (man or company) to an another company, an I right? If I am, try this:

```
create class Company extends V
insert into Company(name) values ("Company001"), ("Company002"), ("Company003")

create class Natuaral_Man extends V
insert into Natural_Man(name) values ("User001")

create class ShareHolderOf extends E

create edge ShareHolderOf from #22:0 to #18:0
create edge ShareHolderOf from #22:0 to #21:0
create edge ShareHolderOf from #20:0 to #21:0
```

this is what you get:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: hi, if we doing it this way, the source or target vertex class could be anything, without any constraint